# Display User Data with React/Meteor Application

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I have been trying various methods to display data from a Meteor fetch within a React template. I don't fully understand why this is so hard to do.

When I use getMeteorData within the template it doesn't display the data when using **{this.data.user._id}**

```
  getMeteorData() {
    return {
        user: Meteor.user()
    };
  },
```

This is the same story when using `componentDidMount`.

I have followed the react & meteor tutorial on the meteor website and they use props. This however feels a lot of work for simply pulling and fetching data.

This is an example of an attempt

```
export var MenuLoggedIn = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'MenuLoggedIn',
  mixins: [
    Router.State, Router.Navigation
  ],
  getMeteorData() {
    return {
        user: Meteor.user()
    };
  },
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      avatarImagePreview: null,
      avatarImage: null
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="menu-structure col-md-12">

          {this.data.user._id}

          <div className="left-menu pull-left">
            <img className="logo" src="/img/logo.png"/>
            <h1 className="eventburger-title">eventburger</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="right-menu">
            <div className="search-bar">
              <i className="fa fa-search"></i>
              <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Harpist, Photographer, Caterer..."/>
            </div>

            {this.data
              ? <img src="/img/avatar.png"/>
              : <img src="/img/placeholder-person.jpg"/>}

            <span>{this.data}
              Feeney</span>

            <a href="/app/inbox">
              <i className="fa fa-envelope"></i>
            </a>
            <a className="head-spacing" href="#" onClick={this.logout}>LOG OUT</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  logout: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Meteor.logout();
    window.location.href = "/login"; //Need to be moved to History
  }
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? I would suspect the `data.user` being `null` until Meteor actually gets the websocket authentication sorted and the user data to the client.

Comment: No errors. It does log the data.user in the console. Do I need to re-render?

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing the actual code that you are using (not sure where the logging occurs - if it's logging correctly in the `render()` method, there should be no problem at all). Generally, the `getMeteorData()` helper is supposed to re-run and, therefore, re-render whenever a dependent reactive data source changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `ReactMeteorData` mixin to make `getMeteorData()` work.

```
mixins: [
  Router.State, Router.Navigation, ReactMeteorData
],
```

https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data